# Find an Item in a LinkedHashSet

Tags: java, linkedhashset

I have a bean putting a query into a `LinkedHashSet` as I want the results going in the order the query is. The query going in as an example is id, forename, surname...... How can I find a name in the `LinkedHashSet` and return the element number for that record. Thanks

Chris

Comment: It's not clear what you're talking about.  Please illustrate with some code.

Comment: Why is the `[jsf]` tag? If you are talking about `LinkedHashSet` in the context of pure Java SE only then, the tag `[jsf]` is utterly superfluous and you should remove it. If you are however, experiencing some difficulties with a `LinkedHashSet` on JSF side, for example, in accessing a `LinkedHashSet` in an XHTML template then, please be more specific and ask as such by editing the question and providing the necessary details with possible suitable examples, if any.

Answer (score 4):

`LinkedHashSet` implements the `Set` interface. The contract for `Set` does not require implementations to keep the items in any particular order. As a result, `Set` does not have methods such as `indexOf(Object object)` or `get(int index)`. As it happens, a `LinkedHashSet` *does* keep the elements in order (insertion order), but this does not mean you can conveniently access the item at a particular index or find the index of an item. It just means that when you iterate over the entire `Set`, the order will be insertion order.

While your question is not entirely clear, it sounds like you should be using a `List` rather than a `Set`. Unless you have a very good reason you should use the most common implementation of `List` which is `ArrayList`. To find the index of an item in a `List` do `list.indexOf(item);`